# How can I query the current sheet in addition to reading data from another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a form that reads data into a spreadsheet. The form results (sheetname = "Form Results 1") looks like

```
Timestamp           Item    Amount  Category
3/10/2021 16:35:16  Test 1  32.24   Sports
3/10/2021 16:38:56  Test 2  34      Groceries
```

The sheet ("Sheet2") I'm reading the form results into is

```
Category        January February    March
Groceries         -       -       $ 34.00 
Sports            -       -       $ 32.24 
Transportation    -       -        -   
Material Items    -       -        -
```

I query the form results to fill the cell values like `=IFERROR(QUERY(formResults, "Select sum(C) where D='Groceries' and month(A)+1=3 label sum(C) ''"), 0)` where `formResults` is the named range that corresponds to `"Form Results 1"!A2:D` and returns `-` if there are no entries for that category.

I'd like to generalize my formula further so I don't need to hardcode the Categories or the month number. I've tried `where D=$A2$ and month(A)=month(D1)` and `where D='Sheet2'!A2 and month(A)=month('Sheet2'!D1)` but both return errors. How can I query the current sheet to include those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace Category with:

`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))`

The formula above gets the first column value of the row

For month:

`COLUMN()-1`

The formula above gets the column of current cell and subtract by 1 to get the month in number form

#### From:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(formResults, "Select sum(C) where D='Groceries' and month(A)+1=3 label sum(C) ''"), 0)`

#### To:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(formResults, "Select sum(C) where D='"&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1))&"' and month(A)+1="&COLUMN()-1&" label sum(C) ''"), 0)`

Just copy the whole formula, select all cells, then paste. (no manual edits to be done per cell)

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample data]

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'Groceries' in A2 and month number in D1, try

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(formResults, "Select sum(C) where D='"&A2&"' and month(A)+1 = "&D1&" label sum(C) ''"), 0)
```

If you have a date in D1, then try

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(formResults, "Select sum(C) where D='"&A2&"' and month(A)+1 = "&month(D1)&" label sum(C) ''"), 0)
```

If the values in A2 and D1 or on a tab/sheet other then the sheet you use the formula on, you'll have to include the sheet name: e.g: '"&Sheet2!A2&"'

Comment: Helpful, but unfortunately the assumptions about the month doesn't hold for this problem because they're labeled as "January", "February", and "March".

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your table is in column E to H my solution is:

```
=query(E1:H,"Select H, sum(G) where E is not null group by H pivot month(E)+1")
```

It works on whole columns
It sums amounts
It adds months when new appear

[image]

**TAKE 2**

According to your remarks I made this formula more detailed and more sticking to your requirements:

It looks like this:

```
={ArrayFormula(vlookup(index(query(formResults,"Select D, sum(C) where A is not null group by D pivot month(A)+1"),1),{"Category","Category";"1","January";"2","February";"3","March";"4","April";"5","May";"6","June";"7","July";"8","August";"9","September";"10","October";"11","November";"12","December"},2,false));
query(
arrayformula(if(
query(formResults,"Select D, sum(C) where A is not null group by D pivot month(A)+1")="",0,
query(formResults,"Select D, sum(C) where A is not null group by D pivot month(A)+1")
)),
"select * offset 1",0)
}
```

[image]

It makes a query that shows proper numbers but month names are in numbers. It's difficult to change as you can't format labels of pivot headings.
I tried to transpose whole query to make pivot values a column, but finally I decided to translate month names using built in dictionary and vlookup formula.

So I take the first row of the query and I translate month names. Then I put original query with one line offset.

I also change null values into 0. I tried change directly into - but then IF formula was changing numbers into strings. I did not like it.

The last part was to add - and format numbers into dollars.
I use custom number format for this.

In order to apply it in your sheet you should mark the range and go to
Menu --> Format --> Number --> More formats --> Custom number format and set:
"$" 0.00;- "$" 0.00;"-"

You can play with this formula here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZAk71VRe2ac85f24R79m-jHApHanYJWTWrj5vjX1FDY/copy

Comment: This would be helpful if the tables were in the same sheet, but this doesn't solve the problem with the month or getting the correct category.